# Passing parameters to a menu?

Tags: python, scripting

I need to be able to define where a specific menu was called. Here is the basic interface:

[image: menu for actions]

Each line has a triangle at the end. When I click the triangle, a menu pops up, which will include a few operators that will change the action relevant to that row. The problem is, I can't figure out how to pass parameters into the menu to tell the menu "this is the action you're changing." I'm probably misunderstanding something about properties. Here's some relevant code.

```py
class ShotsActionChange(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "SHOTS_MT_alter_action"
    bl_label = "Alter action"

    action_id = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="This is a test!")

# ....

# row-generator loop for the panel's draw method, where this menu is called:
    def action_row(self, layout, action, object=None):
        iconi = self.get_data_icon(object)
        obj_text = ""

        if object is not None:
            obj_text = object + " :: "

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(icon=iconi, text="")
        row.label(text=obj_text + action)
        row.menu("SHOTS_MT_alter_action", text="", icon="DOWNARROW_HLT")
```

What I want is for that last line to do something along the lines of:

```
row.menu("SHOTS_MT_alter_action", text="", icon="DOWNARROW_HLT").action_id = action
```

And that way, I can pass something into the menu. It spouts errors right now, but I don't think I know enough about the API to know whether this is impossible or just needs to be reworked. The menu itself is a hub for multiple operators, but do I need an operator that controls the opening of the menu? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45845/how-to-create-submenus-with-dynamic-content

Comment: Not only was it related, it answered my question!